# How to work on large database using Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I have a database of size 2GB. I am using Lucene indexing technique to make search faster. I have found a problem i.e. when I used to load the data into memory, an error message shown, "out of memory;java heap size".
   Is there any option to load the data without increasing the java heap size? 
I am using 2GB RAM. I have not find any solution to this problem. Is there any solution?
Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Lucene can easy index and search over 200Gb data with less that 10Gb of memory.

1. Use latest version of Lucene.
2. Commit index often. You have to keep uncommited changes in memory and need some additional memory to commit it and merge segments.
3. Tune memory consumption by `IndexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(double)` and related functions and check index `MergePolicy` if you hit OOM when merging.
4. Avoid using stored fields for big data blobs. For DB indexing only id is enough to be stored.
5. Use proper field analyzers, term dictionary will be small as possible.

Some related links:

1. [Lucene's RAM usage for searching](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/07/lucenes-ram-usage-for-searching.html) (old, but still actual)
2. [IndexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(double)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html#setRAMBufferSizeMB(double))
3. [MergePolicy](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.html)